# Separate objects from binary volume

Tags: algorithm, matlab, 3d, image-segmentation

I'm using MATLAB.

I have a three dimensional array filled with logicals. This array represents data of a cylinder with N uniformly shaped, but arbitrary orientated staples in it. The volume is discretized in voxels (3 dimensional pixels) and a logical '1' means 'at this point in the cylinder IS a part of a staple', while a '0' means 'at this point in the cylinder is air'.
The following picture contains **ONE** two dimensional **slice** of the full volume. Imagine the complete volume composed of such slices. **White means '1' and black means '0'.**
[image: one slice of the volume]

To my problem now: I have to **separate each staple** as good as possible.
The output products should be N three dimensional arrays with only the voxels belonging to a certain staple being '1', everything else '0'. So that I have arrays that only contain the data of one staple.

The biggest problem is, that '1's of different staples can lie next to each other **(touching each other and being entangled)**, making it difficult to decide to which staple they belong to.
Simplifying is the fact, that boundary voxels of a staple may be cut away, I can work with any output array which preserves the approximate shape of the original staple.

Maybe somebody of you can provide an idea how such a problem could be solved, or even name me algorithms which I can take a look at.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try eroding your data by one voxel, and then running connected components on it.

Comment: [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) is always with best accuracy when you know exactly what shape you're finding. But not very computationally efficient. Just think of it as the bruteforce approach of pattern recognition.

Comment: It will help if you can tell us what can you assume about the staples. Will they all have the same size? What about the proportion of the "legs" and the "body"? Can they touch or go through each other? Is the data noisy? What do you recognize a staple by?

Comment: They all have the same size. The long side of the staple is about 2 times as long as the legs. They absolutely both touch each other and go through each other. I Can't say much about the noisyness. The last question isn't quite clear to me. I have no algorithm to let the computer recognize a staple - that's my problem.

Comment: What I mean by the last question is "What logic can you use to distinguish a full valid staple from something like, say, two perfectly aligned staple like |_|__|_|. In this case, since you know the size is fixed, you then know there are 2 staples not 3."

Comment: These information are important for using Hough transform. But it's a bit long to explain here what Hough transform does, so you will have to read that by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Since the staples are many pixel objects, you can reduce noise using [3d median filtering](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30853-field-mapping-toolbox/content/medfilt3.m)  or `bwareaopen` to start with. Then  [`bwlabeln`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabeln.html) can be used to label connected components in the binary array. Then you can use
[REGIONPROPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to further analyze each connected object, and see if this is a standalone staple or more.  This can be done  using features such as  'Perimeter' to identify different cases, but you'll have to investigate yourself these  and other regionprops  features .

Comment: That will work extremely well. Under the condition that the staple never touch or overlap each other, and also that the data is not noisy.

Comment: of course, but for that you have other tools such as median filters etc. I'll try to edit the answer better...

Comment: Median filter will help with noise, certainly. but not so much if the staples decide to entangle themselves. And you know what, staples are **thin**. I think median of most areas will be '0'

Comment: The staples are both, touching each other and entangled.

Comment: That is a good idea, thank you for that. But what I'm actually experiencing is, that the 3d median filtering function broadens touching areas - quite the opposite effect I hoped for. I need something which scrapes the outer pixels off.

Comment: @Bafika, instead of median filter try to use `bwareaopen` with the right # of pixels and connectivity.